# SQL query to get all the distinct words in a table where the related id is in an array

Tags: mysql, sql

I am in over my head with this sql query.

I need to get all the distinct words in a table where the element_id is in an array.

```
 word | element_id
------+-----------
 cat  | 1 
 dog  | 1 
 cat  | 2 
 dog  | 2 
 rat  | 1 
 rat  | 3
```

I would like to find all the words that have the `element_id` of 1 and 2.

In this case I would like to return **cat** and **dog** but not **rat**.

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

`select distinct word from words where element_id = 1 and element_id = 2`

Comment: group by, having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select word
from words
where element_id in (1, 2)
group by word
having count(*) = 2;
```

This assumes that your table doesn't have duplicate rows.

If performance is an issue, then:

```
select w.word
from words w
where w.element_id = 1 and
      exists (select 1 from words w2 where w2.word = w.word and w2.element_id = 2);
```

This can take advantage of an index on `words(word, element_id)` and `words(element_id)` (two separate indexes).

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using `avg` and `sum` aggregate functions within a `grouping` select statement that includes `having` clause as :

```
select word
  from words
 group by word
having avg(nvl(element_id,0)) = 1.5 and sum(nvl(element_id,0)) = 3;
```

assuming `element_id` is a nullable integer column.

Or

```
select word
  from words
 group by word
having avg(element_id) = 1.5 and sum(element_id) = 3;
```

as `element_id` is a non-nullable integer column.

*P.S. In this way, no need to write the ids explicitly.*